# Create a checkbox per loaded layer in a QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I want to create check boxes inside a listview in my plugin dynamically based on the number of layers loaded in QGIS. I would like to know is there any similar existing plugin in QGIS so that I may refer the code and try implementing in mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late post but I implemented something similar recently so thought to share it. You could create a [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html) by defining a new function in your plugin. For example:

```
def refresh_listView(self):
    qListView = self.dockwidget.listView
    model = QStandardItemModel()

    for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():   
        item = QStandardItem(layer.name())
        check = Qt.Checked
        item.setCheckState(check)
        item.setCheckable(True)
        model.appendRow(item)

    qListView.setModel(model)
```

Then in your `run()` function, you could connect the function slot to a signal so that whenever a layer is added/removed, the QListView will be updated:

```
 def run(self, checked):
    self.refresh_listView()

    if checked:
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().layersAdded.connect(self.refresh_listView)
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().layersRemoved.connect(self.refresh_listView)
    else:
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().layersAdded.disconnect(self.refresh_listView)
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().layersRemoved.disconnect(self.refresh_listView)
```

---

Example:

[image: QlistView example]

Notes:

1. The updated QListView simply adds all currently loaded layers and sets their checkbox to `True`.
2. The `run()` function I used can be checked to allow the signals to be disconnected from the slots.